# Convert one string to a list of strings based on certain numbers inside the string

Tags: python, string

I'm new to python and need to find a way to format my digital signals in text format. Specifically I need to convert the string from string_old to list_new below. Hope someone can help out here!

```
string_old = 'clock[5,4,1,0]'

list_new = ['clock[5]','clock[4]','clock[1]','clock[0]']
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: -1 This question shows no research or effort on the part of the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `regex` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs='clock[5,4,1,0]'
>>> nums = re.findall("\d+",strs)        #find all the numbers in string
>>> word = re.search("\w+",strs).group() #find the word in the string 

#now iterate over the numbers and use string formatting to get the required output.
>>> [ "{0}[{1}]".format(word,x) for x in nums] 
['clock[5]', 'clock[4]', 'clock[1]', 'clock[0]']
```

Comment: Nice job :), I don know how you can be so fast.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. This totally helps. Just one typo at the last line, 'nums' instead of 'num'. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that does what you ask, using a combination of regular expressions, split and list comprehension:

```
import re

string_old = 'clock[5,4,1,0]'
match = re.search('(.*)\[(.*)\]', string_old)
if match:
    indices = match.group(2).split(',')
    list_new = ['{0}[{1}]'.format(match.group(1), ind) for ind in indices]
    print list_new
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative which uses Python's own parser to process the string - so it will raise `SyntaxError` if it's duff. It's probably not as easily understandable as a regex or splitting, but is a reasonable alternative - especially if you find you're doing a bit more of this stuff (alternatively look at `pyparsing` which can handle these kinds of input):

```
import ast

s = 'clock[5,4,1,0]'
slc = ast.parse(s).body[0].value
print ['{}[{}]'.format(slc.value.id, el.n) for el in slc.slice.value.elts]
# ['clock[5]', 'clock[4]', 'clock[1]', 'clock[0]']
```